# Replace isnull to 0 in case statement of sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a query like this,

```
select * from (      
select  a.CreatedMonth,Total_Days,case when a.Type = 'Invalid_Question' then 'Invalid'       
                  when a.Type = 'Valid_Question' then 'Valid' 
                  end as Type      
from      
(      
  select  CreatedMonth,Type,sum(Questions_Count*LastDays) /sum(Questions_Count) as Total_Days      
 from   #t       
 group by  CreatedMonth,Type      
) a      
)as d pivot(sum(Total_Days) for Type in (Invalid, Valid)) as p
```

But in the output, Valid is null. I have to set it's value from null to 0. Also where do I modify the code, in the case statement or in pivot?

This is the result I'm getting currently,

```
CreatedMonth    Invalid    Valid
    1              50        32
    2              63        47 
    3              70       NULL
```

How can I do that?

Comment: If you just want to return 0 instead of NULL, use an ISNULL in the outermost query.

Comment: Where in outer query? The case statement?

Comment: You should replace the "select * from" with "select CreatedMonth, isnull(Invalid,0) as Invalid, isnull(Valid,0) as Valid ..."

Comment: Exactly as James says.   the outer query is the SELECT * FROM (.

Answer (score 0):

```
select CreatedMonth
      ,ISNULL(Invalid,0) AS Invalid 
      ,ISNULL(Valid  ,0) AS Valid
from (      
select  a.CreatedMonth
       ,Total_Days
       ,case 
             when a.[Type] = 'Invalid_Question' then 'Invalid'       
             when a.[Type] = 'Valid_Question'   then 'Valid' 
        end as [Type]      
from      
(      
  select  CreatedMonth
         ,[Type]
         ,sum(Questions_Count*LastDays) /sum(Questions_Count) as Total_Days      
  from   #t       
 group by  CreatedMonth,[Type]      
) a      
)as d pivot(sum(Total_Days) 
            for [Type] 
            in ([Invalid], [Valid])) as p
```

Comment: add some sample data and desired output in your question,  maybe then I can see whats really going on